Tailwind CSS is not being applied on a specific page
I am created a simple blog post using tailwind and node.js. I made a header and a footer for my template now when I created a post.ejs page that renders dynamically and added a header and footer to the page the styles of tailwind doesn't apply on the page.
app.get('/post/:topic', (req, res) => {
    let topic = _.lowerCase(req.params.topic);
    let matchfound = false;

    if (posts.length === 0) {
        res.status(404).send('<h1>No posts available</h1>');
        return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        let eachpost = _.lowerCase(posts[i].title);
        if (eachpost === topic) {
            res.render('post', {
                Title: posts[i].title,
                page: posts[i].title,
                paragraph: posts[i].content
            });
            matchfound = true;
            break;  // Exit the loop after finding a match
        }
    }

    if (!matchfound) {
        res.status(404).send('<h1>Post not found</h1>');
    }
}); 

I Think the reason is when i try to get this dynamic parameter app.get('/post/:topic', (req, res) => { because if i simply write /post the tailwind works correctly but then it will not create
This is my post.ejs page.
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>

    <main>
    <div class="heading">
      <h1 class="text-3xl text-blue-700 m-5"><%= page %></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="para">
      <p class="ml-8"><%= paragraph %></p>
    </div>
  </main>


  <%- include("partials/footer"); -%>

I am expecting the header and footer to work correctly and apply tailwind classes.

we cannot see any of your error

Make sure that Tailwind CSS is correctly included in your header partial. The header.ejs file should include the necessary CSS file. Please check your CSS file attachment.
Check this example and try to check with the inspect element.
